# Remove the same notification from ios notification center

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, nsnotificationcenter

Is there a way to detect the previous notification in notification centre, & remove the previous notification if it is same as current & keep the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can remove previous notification. when 1st notification comes, keep it in `NSUserDefaults` when 2nd notification comes, check `NSUserDefaults` contains 1st notification then get notification object from `NSUserDefaults` , cancel it `cancelLocalNotification` and also remove from `NSUserDefaults`, now you schedule your 2nd notification.

Note - Purpose to keep notification object in `NSUserDefaults`, so you can retrieve 1st notification object even after your device or app gets restart.